# Error when writing to a .txt file and using "\n" for a new line python

Tags: python, python-2.7, newline

I think the problem is that I need to combine str and int so I'm using the "(str(myvariable)) and the parentheses are throwing it off. I'm not sure about that, though. Here is the code:

```
 #Save
if "ave" in animal: #- the s because of the .strip("s") on line 9
    with open(timeStamped('AnimalCount.txt'),'w') as outf:
        outf.write('Pronghorn: ' + (str(pronghorn)) \n 'Deer: ' + (str(deer))) 
    print " "
    print "Saved"
    print " "
```

the problem is on line 4. Thanks!

Comment: `\n` has to be a part of a string (in quotes). So `outf.write('Pronghorn: ' + (str(pronghorn)) + '\nDeer: ' + (str(deer)))`

Comment: That did it! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the new line character to be within the quotes:

```
'Pronghorn: ' + (str(pronghorn)) + '\n Deer: ' + (str(deer))
```